# Problem with '/usr/share/doc/libperl5.26'

Tags: virtualbox, backup, deja-dup

Ubuntu!

Well, I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) on VirtualBox with a Windows 7 Ultimate host.

When I click Deja Dup Backup, it loads, but when I click Back Up Now it tells me to install 'duplicity, python-gi'.

So I click Install and then it gives me this:

```
Backup failed

Error when installing package: trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libperl45.26/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of changelog.Debian.gz
```

Can somebody help me or can I not backup on VirtualBox? I'll post if any other programs do this too.

Answer (score 0):

Install the missing dependencies using `apt` instead of via the Backup application. Open a terminal and:

```
sudo apt install python-gi duplicity
```

This seems to be a deb packaging glitch introduced with 18.04. `deja-dup` should have a dependency on `python-gi`.